# Convert adjacency matrix into pairwise table format with Perl

Tags: perl, unix, matrix

I have a data that looks like this (adjacency matrix):

```
foo bar 0.14 qux 0.2
bar foo 0.14 qux 0.4
qux foo 0.2 bar 0.4
```

What I want to do is to convert them into pairwise table:

```
  foo bar 0.14
  foo qux 0.2
  bar qux 0.4
```

But I'm stuck with the following code. What's the correct way to do it?

```
   use strict;

   while ( <DATA> ) {
        chomp;
        next if (/^>/);
        my $line = $_;
        my @els = split(/\s+/,$line);
        my $pivot = $els[0];

        my $genen = '';
        my $score = '';

        foreach  my $id ( 0 .. $#els  ) {
            next if ($id == 0);
            if ( $id % 2 != 0 ) {
                # gene name
                #print "$els[$id]\n";
                $genen = $els[$id];

            }
            else {
                #
                $score = $els[$id];
            }

    print "$pivot   $genen  $score\n";

        }

    #print "--\n";

    }
__DATA__
foo bar 0.3 qux 0.2
bar foo 0.15 qux 0.4
qux foo 0.3 bar 0.4
```

Comment: Surely the weight of `0.3` is a typo for `0.14`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated in response to comments**

Here's a simplified version that would appear to be more self-explanatory, and a little bit more robust:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub transpose
{
    my $pivot =  shift || die "pivot required";
    while (my ($genen, $score) = (shift, shift))
    {
        last unless $score and $genen;
        print "$pivot   $genen  $score\n";
    }
}

for (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    transpose(split /\s+/) unless m/^>/;
}
__DATA__
foo bar 0.3 qux 0.2
bar foo 0.15 qux 0.4
qux foo 0.3 bar 0.4
```

Output:

```
foo   bar  0.3
foo   qux  0.2
bar   foo  0.15
bar   qux  0.4
qux   foo  0.3
qux   bar  0.4
```

Comment: Thanks. I the following data (just one line): http://dpaste.com/1068656/plain/ ; But somehow my algo failed...
For example I expect it not to print 'Unigene14119_All        Unigene39653_All        0.234869'

Comment: yes. just single line. Data is too large to include all. I just show first line.

Comment: @neversaint I have taken the test data to produce a more legible, simpler version, and updated my answer. Hope you like it.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3} {print $1,$4,$5}' file
```

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't scale so well for the OP's [real data sample](http://dpaste.com/1068656/plain/)